# Installing 12.10 on Macbook Pro Retina with rEFIt

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, macbook, refit

I have tried many attempts to install 12.10 on my Mac Retina following [this guide](http://www.warp1337.com/content/install-ubuntu-1210-quantal-quetzal-macbook-pro-101-retina-solved) but it boots just once and after I installed Nvidia drivers it doesn't boot any further.

I need some help.

Comment: please specify EXACTLY what retina model you have for example ,  11,4

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem following that guid which I JUST solved.  I found that step #5 in http://cberner.com/2012/10/19/installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-macbook-pro-retina/ which was used to install the nvidia driver needs to be done after an update (I think?) as if you build it for your current kernel ('uname -r') and then update the new kernel won't be able to load the graphics driver.  For me at least, after the install I had 3.5.0-17-generic and after the update 3.5.0-23-generic.

I did the basic install, then first thing I updated the system, then a reboot, then step 3 in cberner, then step 5, and then it seemed to work.  I just managed to install CUDA and run some tests with it as well, so it's definitely working.

What I can't do though is change the resolution from 2880x1800 which is a bit too 'small' for me, but at least it's working now.

Hope this works for you!  I'm quite new to Linux myself so sorry if this isn't very clear. :(

Answer (score 0):

Only Ubuntu 13.04 works with Macbookpro retina. 3.8 linux support Macbookpro retina, previous versions of the kernel are problematic.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 in my macbookpro retina in external usb hard drive in posting this reply.